# LESS nesting with bootstrap mixins not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm currently messing around with Bootstrap and LESS, and tried to do the following:

LESS:

```
.class1 {
  .jumbotron;
  div {
    .container();
    color: white;
  }
}
```

HTML (just the part that matters of course):

```
<div class="class1">
  <div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the .container() mixin refuses to work when in a nest. Note that the text color is indeed white, which indicates the problem is only with Bootstrap mixins.
[image]
Indeed, if I do this:

```
.class1 div {
    .container();
    color: white;
}
```

It works like a charm.
[image]
But I'm sure LESS isn't supposed to work like that, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ".jumbotron;" valid LESS? I've never seen a class name with a semi colon just after it.

Comment: It's a Bootstrap thing. Indeed, for some reason (I'm just now learning LESS tbh) it works whether I use (); or just ; if the mixin does not ask for an argument

Comment: But isn't jumbotron just a class? It's a function above?

Comment: It will help if we could see the content of jumbotron if it is a fucntion.

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/less/jumbotron.less there you go

Comment: why don't you try putting your jumbotron in the container. try please.

Comment: @Bhansa it does work, but I want the Jumbotron to extend to full width, which the container undoes.

Comment: @Rafael My bad, I did not know you could apply the content of a class like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.class1 div {
    .container();
    color: white;
}
```

is working, so the problem comes from your selector or something between the two selectors. Look at `.jumbotron;` and edit it, so you will resolve the conflict.

Comment: That ended up doing it. I don't know why in the name of Turing would the guys at Twitter do something like `jumbotron .container {max-width: 100%;}`, but they totally did.

Comment: Glad to help you :)